# How can I iterate through different types of dictionaries using one generic method?

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-core

I have a `HttpContext context` and I iterate through some of its `Request` properties to collect info. Currently I do it this way:

```
if (context.Request.Headers?.Keys != null)
{
    var items = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var key in context.Request.Headers.Keys)
    {
        items.AppendLine(key + " = " + context.Request.Headers[key]);
    }
    result.Headers = items.ToString();
}
if (context.Request.Form?.Keys != null)
{
    var items = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var key in context.Request.Form.Keys)
    {
         items.AppendLine(key + " = " + context.Request.Form[key]);
    }
    result.Form = items.ToString();
}
if (context.Request.Query?.Keys != null)
{
    var items = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var key in context.Request.Query.Keys)
    {
        items.AppendLine(key + " = " + context.Request.Query[key]);
    }
    result.Query = items.ToString();
}
```

I want to convert this repetitive code to a generic method (if you can suggest any other ways, I would be fine with them, too). I tried writing a generic method:

```
private static string ParseKeys<T>(IDictionary<object, object> dict)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var key in dict.Keys)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(key + " = " + dict[key]);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

and calling it like this:

```
result.Headers = ParseKeys<IHeaderDictionary>(context.Request.Headers);
result.Form = ParseKeys<IFormCollection>(context.Request.Form);
result.Query = ParseKeys<IQueryCollection>(context.Request.Query);
```

But I get such errors: `cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHeaderDictionary' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<object, object>'`

I tried various combinations but I still couldn't manage to avoid errors. Am I trying to do impossible here, or is there a simple to do what I want?

Comment: What happens if you change `ParseKeys` to take `IDictionary<string, StringValues> dict` instead? Or `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>> dict`?

Comment: How do you expect `dict[key]` to be converted to a string here? What if the dictionary holds a bunch of complex class objects for example?

Comment: But all those 3 types you mention all implement `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>>` so you really don't need a generic method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those collections you mention ([IHeaderDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iheaderdictionary), [IFormCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.IFormCollection) and [IQueryCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.IQueryCollection)) all implement the same interface: `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>>` so here you don't need a generic method. Instead, you can do something like this:

```
private static string ParseKeys(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>> values)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(value.Key + " = " + string.Join(", ", value.Value));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

And call it as you were previously:

```
result.Headers = ParseKeys(context.Request.Headers);
result.Form = ParseKeys(context.Request.Form);
result.Query = ParseKeys(context.Request.Query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a generic method, but you are not using the generic type parameter `T`. As far as the `IHeaderDictionary` and the `IFormCollection`, it is enough to accept an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>>`, since both interfaces inherit it:

```
private static string ParseKeys(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>> dict)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var keyValuePair in dict)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(keyValuePair.Key + " = " + String.Join(", ", keyValuePair.Value));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

As far as the `IQueryCollection` is concerned, it is an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>>`. You can easily transform this to the required type with an iterator:

```
private static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>> Transform(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>> source) {
    foreach(var item in source) {
        yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string[]>(item.Key, item.Value.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Eventually, you can call the method like:

```
result.Headers = ParseKeys(context.Request.Headers);
result.Form = ParseKeys(context.Request.Form);
result.Query = ParseKeys(Transform(context.Request.Query));
```

Comment: Why use `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>>` over `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>>`?

Comment: Depends on which [IFormCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.iformcollection(v=vs.113).aspx) you are using.

Comment: The OP is using .NET Core - not that `IFormCollection`.